# How many articles within Gender and/or Target Audience [SQL]

Tags: sql

I want to query how many articles are available within a Gender. Output should look like this:

|  | Men | Women |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sneakers | 150 | 122 |
| Boots | 40 | 309 |

It must be something like, but I don't know how to fill it in correctly:
Select
countif(case when Gender = 'Men' then Articles) end as Men
countif(case when Gender = 'Women' then Articles) end as Women
From

Thanks in advance!

t must be something like, but I don't know how to fill it in correctly: Select countif(case when Gender = 'Men' then Articles) end as Men countif(case when Gender = 'Women' then Articles) end as Women From

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation here.  A general SQL solution might be:

```sql
SELECT
    Article,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Men'   THEN 1 END) AS Men,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Women' THEN 1 END) AS Women
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Article;
```